# Issue of positioning of anchor tag in Firefox browser on hover

Tags: javascript, asp.net, firefox

```
function func_showmenu(oevent,  stabid, irowindex) {
        var otable, orow, ocol;
        otable = eval(document.all.tabmenu);
        for(var ictr=otable.rows.length-1;ictr>=0;ictr--)
            otable.deleteRow(ictr);

                orow = otable.insertRow();
                ocol = orow.insertCell();
                ocol.innerHTML = "<a href=javascript:func_adddoc('moddoc',"+irowindex+")>Modify</a>";

        orow = otable.insertRow();
        ocol = orow.insertCell();
        ocol.innerHTML = "<a href=javascript:func_delrow('" + stabid + "'," + irowindex + ")>Delete</a>";
        otable.style.posTop = document.body.scrollTop + oevent.clientY;
        otable.style.posLeft = document.body.scrollLeft + oevent.clientX;
        otable.style.display = "";
}
```

As i hover on my row the modify/delete link comes at the bottom of the page in firefox browser where as in other browser it works fine. Please help.

[image: This is how modify/delete is coming]

Comment: you can see the error console in firefox or you can use the [developer toolbar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/) add on to see the java-script errors.

Comment: there is no error , position is not working properly

Comment: @rohitsingh can you produce a fiddle

Comment: i have not used fiddle before but i have added the image